# C# FindElement(By...) with two criteria

Tags: c#, html, selenium, button, automation

I am currently trying to automate a checkout process. Now I am stuck, the buttons on the site displaying the sizes are nearly identical, they only differ in value

[image]

That's why I wanted to ask if I can differ them by two criteria like class + value.

Code:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace selenium1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();



            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.off---white.com/en-de/shopping/off-white-odsy-1000-sneakers-14760681");

            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.());

            element.Click();


        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You can club up the **value** attribute along with any other attribute e.g. `data-test`, to construct the locators which would identify the element uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

To `click()` on the element with text as **39** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.off---white.com/en-de/shopping/off-white-odsy-1000-sneakers-14760681");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input[data-test='sizeSelector'][value='23']"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.off---white.com/en-de/shopping/off-white-odsy-1000-sneakers-14760681");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@data-test='sizeSelector' and @value='23']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: works well, but the button isn't interactable. How can I still select the size? Can you help me with that?

Comment: @WalterSommer Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: ExpectedConditions is underlined in red and I can't import anything to get it away

Comment: okay figured out, how to get ExectedConditions, now all sizes get selected for like 1 ms and then unselected

Answer (score 2):

you could use a CSS selector.

for example: `css = element_name[<attribute_name>='<value>']`

So in your case it would be:
`IWebElement element1 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value='25']") 
 IWebElement element2 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[value='27']")`

[This article should help](https://www.testingexcellence.com/css-selectors-selenium-webdriver/)